# I tried to refactor my mongoose operation, but don't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to refactor my mongoose code, because it looks repetitive

Here's the code

```
   var updateResume = function(query, id, set, value) {
    User.update({query: id}, {'$set': {
        set: value,
    }}, function(err, found) {
        // Do nothing
    });
}


 app.get('/testing', function(req, res) {
    updateResume('resume.educations._id', req.body.education_id,
            'resume.educations.$.school', req.body.education_school);

 });
```

When I don't put it in a function it works just fine.

Can Mongoose/Mongodb expert tell me what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a variable as the name of a key in JavaScript you need to assign it with bracket `[]` notation. Otherwise the value on the left side ( the key ) is taken as a literal:

```
var updateResume = function(query, id, set, value,callback) {
    var Query = { },
        update = { "$set": {} };

    Query[query] = id;
    update.$set[set] = value;        

    User.update(Query, update, callback);
};

app.get('/testing', function(req, res) {
    updateResume(
        'resume.educations._id', req.body.education_id,
        'resume.educations.$.school', req.body.education_school,
        function(err,result) {
            // do something in here
        }
    );
});
```

Also since the operation is async, you really should pass in the handling callback to your generic method, rather than try to handle inside yourself. It's much more flexible that way.

Answer (score -2):

I see two problems in your code:

1) You are trying to use the value of parameter `set` to dynamically set  attribute name you wish to change. It won't work this way.

There is more than one way to do what you want. In JavaScript 6, for example, you could just change this part to:

```
User.update({query: id}, {'$set': {
    [set]: value,
}}, function(err, found) {
    // Do nothing
});
```

But **the above code won't work, unless** you are running node with `--harmony` flag or you are transpiling it with babel, for example (I suppose probably not your case).

In order to get things easy to reproduce, I will suggest this version:

```
var changes = {};
changes[set] = value;
User.update({query: id}, {'$set': changes}, function(err, found) {
    // We will take care of it soon
});
```

The second problem is about the async nature of node.js. You can't just "do nothing" in your callback. It **seems** to work, but things will begin to get weird someday with your code and you will never discover the problem.

When you just ignore a callback, your next line of code continues to run, even if this operations hasn't finished yet.

It means that if next line try to read this record, it may be not changed yet (maybe yes maybe no), and your code will "works" sometimes and sometimes not.

I prefer this way, using promises:

```
function updateResume(query, id, set, value) {
    var changes = {};
    changes[set] = value;

    return User.update({query: id}, {'$set': changes});
}

app.get('/testing', function(req, res) {
   updateResume(
       'resume.educations._id',
       req.body.education_id,
       'resume.educations._id',
       req.body.education_id
   ).then( function() {
       res.send("OK"); 
   }).catch( function (err) {
       res.send("NOK");
   })
});
```

Comment: Just noticed I had copied his updateResume function version in place of mine in my last code sample. Corrected.